# MS Sql 2008 index on two columns for 2D position

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have table named "Map" with structure "XPos int, YPos int, FieldType int".

The "XPos" and "YPos" are primary key. There are several tables depending on this table, referencing "XPos" and "YPos" columns.

In "Map" table users can not add or remove rows. Rarely is changed value in "FieldType" column.

The most selects looks like:

```
SELECT M.XPos, M.YPos, M.FieldType, N.NoteTitle, N.NoteDescription
FROM Map AS M
INNER JOIN Note AS N ON M.XPos = N.XPos AND M.YPos = N.YPos
WHERE M.XPos >= 248 AND M.XPos <= 311
      AND M.YPos >= 578 AND M.YPos <= 715
```

How should I index it for good select performance?. Now I have one clustered index on "XPos, YPos", but I don't think this is best way.

Comment: Quick question: have you ran SQL Server's Database Engine Tuning Advisor? It can really help, especially if you can simulate the workload your DB will typically experience.

Comment: What makes you think the index isn't effective? Clustered indexes are usually very good for 'range queries', i.e. where the search predicate is between specific values. Are you having performance problems? Have you reviewed the query plan and used the DTA as @Hal suggested?

Comment: How is the `Note` table indexed?

Comment: @Hal, @Pondlife: DTA shows, the PK clustered index is used (XPos, YPos) and recomends create new non-clustered index on (XPos, YPos). It does not make sense for me.

Comment: @Ed Harper: "Note" table is indexed by "XPos, YPos" - same as "Map" table.

Comment: @TcKS: Try it and run some benchmarks. I managed to pull of a very good performance increase in a project because of those strange recommendations... can't harm to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

create an index on the fields your selecting, and in the included columns add the fields your filtering by.

here's an example:

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Cover] ON [dbo].[tblPROJECTS] 
(
    [QUOTESTATUS] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Project_Amount],
[SubCost],
[VendorCost],
[CustCost],
[crmProjID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

this index would work well for a statement like this:

select
QuoteStatus
from dbo.tblProjects
where Project_Amount>0
and SubCost=0
and VendorCost>0
and CustCost>0
and crmProjID=2

Comment: Sorry, I realy don't understand what exactly do you think, I should do.